# Inverse functions (elementary)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $f(x) = x+5$ which is symmetrical about line $y = x$ with $h^{-1}(3x+1)$. I want to derive $h(x)$. So I find the inverse of $f(x)$ first which is $x-5$ and equate it to $h^{-1}(3x+1)$ I must be missing simple but how to proceed from here?

Comment: If f and g are "symmetrical about line y= x" then y= f(x) is the **same** as "x= g(y).  So, here, x+ 5= h(3x+ 1).  Let u= 3x+ 1.  Then h(u)= x+ 5.  Write x+ 5 in terms of u and you have your function, h.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are symmetrical about $y = x$.  Do you understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at $$h^{-1}(3x+1)=x-5.$$
So now you substitute $y=3x+1$ or $x=\frac{y-1}3$ and you get
$$h^{-1}(y)=\frac{y-1}3-5.$$
You now simply invert this to

$$h(x)=3(x+5)+1=3x+16.$$

Comment: Clear and succint. Thanks!

Comment: @xiangqi No need to thank me! An upvote and/or accepting the answer will do it as weill ;)